# How can I change the gamemode without tricks/commands?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a world of survival but I want to change it to creative without deactivating the achievements, I have tried some editors but none works in Minecraft Windows 10 any solution?

Comment: Sorry. No possible way. Thats would be kinda cheating cus ur going to creative while haveing achievements.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can not go into creative without having cheats allowed. So the only way to change from survival to creative is to type `/gamemode 1` and the other game modes are `/gamemode 0` (survival) and `/gamemode 3`. (spectator mode)